# how to show image and text inline with text in between the line

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a image of 20 x 50 px and want to show it inline with some text of font 20px size . 
 I want text in the middle of the line, Text is stick to lower, i want it in middle of the line. Since image height is 50px and font is 20px. 
I have tried padding the image (Padding-top: 20px;) but it affects whole line.

```
    <div  style="display:inline; ">
      <a href="./waterbill" title="Water Bill Detail"> 
       <img style="width: 20px; height: 50px; padding-top: 25px;" src="images/useful/phed-water-drop.png" />
      </a>&nbsp; 
   </div>
  <div  style="display:inline; white-space:nowrap;">
    <a href="./waterbill" title="Water Bill Detail"> Water Bill Details </a>
  </div>
```

> Is there any way to show text in the middle (y axis) of the line, with image in its left ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "I want text in the middle of the line, Text is stick to lower, i want it in middle of the line." Any chance of an image to depict what you desire?

Comment: as image height is 50px and font is of 20px, i want text in the middle (vertical) of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use *verticle-align* as :

```
<div style=" margin-top: 25px;">
  <div style="display: inline; white-space: nowrap;">
   <a href="./waterbill" title="Water Bill Detail">
      <img style="width: 20px; height: 30px; vertical-align: middle;" src="images/useful/phed-water-drop.png"/>
   </a>&nbsp;
  <a href="./waterbill" title="Water Bill Detail" style="vertical-align: sub;">Water Bill Details </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using exact pixels then you can use something like this-

```
<div style="display:inline; vertical-align:middle ">
 <a href="./waterbill" title="Water Bill Detail">
 <img style="width: 20px; height: 50px; " src="Coding.jpg" />
 </a>&nbsp;
 <a href="./waterbill" style="position:absolute;top:25px" title="Water Bill Detail"> Water Bill Details </a>
</div>
```